# Viewlayer/composite shortcut

Tags: shortcut, viewlayers

After rendering with F12, you can switch between slots by pressing 1,2,3... depending on the slot you want to go to. Is there a shortcut to switch between before/after composite, instead of choosing in the top right menu ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it seems there is no shortcut for switching between 'raw' view layer and composite. Also, you cannot assign the dropdown menu (or any of its contents) to the quick favorites [Q].

But there's a cheap workaround that I like to use (because I am not a big fan of compositor's *Backdrop* function):
In Edit > Preferences > Interface > Temporary Editors, set **Render In** to "Image Editor". In the Compositing Tab, create two Image Editors (I like to do a *Vertical Split*) and set one to *View Layer* and the other to *Composite*:

[image]

I know, it's cheap. But at least you can compare the result without switching back and forth.

Comment: I see. I appreciate you taking the time to respond.